# how to add returned data to the existing template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, ecmascript-6

I am using ember. I intercept one component's button click in controller. The click is to trigger a new report request. When a new report request is made, I want the newly made request to appear on the list of requests that I currently show. How do I make ember refresh the page without obvious flicker?

Here is my sendAction code:

```
actions: {
    sendData: function () {
  this.set('showLoading', true);

  let data = {
    startTime: date.normalizeTimestamp(this.get('startTimestamp')),
    endTime: date.normalizeTimestamp(this.get('endTimestamp')),
    type: constants.ENTERPRISE.REPORTING_PAYMENT_TYPE
  };

  api.ajaxPost(`${api.buildV3EnterpriseUrl('reports')}`, data).then(response => {
    this.set('showLoading', false);
    return response.report;
  }).catch(error => {
    this.set('showLoading', false);
    if (error.status === constants.HTTP_STATUS.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT) {
      this.notify.error(this.translate('reports.report_timedout'), 
this.translate('reports.report_timedout_desc'));
    } else {
      this.send('error', error);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few think you should consider. Generaly you want to have variable that holds an array which you are render in template in loop. For example: you fetch your initial set of data in route and pass it on as `model` variable.

```
// route.js
model() { return []; }

// controller
actions: {
    sendData() {
        foo().then(payload => {
            // important is to use pushObjects method. 
            // Plain push will work but wont update the template.
            this.get('model').pushObjects(payload);
        });
    }
}
```

This will automatically update template and add additional items on the list.

Boilerplate for **showLoading**

You can easily refactor your code and use [ember-concurency](https://ember-concurrency.com/). Check their docs, afair there is example fitting your usecase.

Comment: Thank you but I tried that already and still get the same error. This is for an ember-engine if that makes a difference.